# FIRDatabaseHandle value or childChanged

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking for a way to read data form a child and also have it live updated.

I have seen some code examples where people first fetch data using:

```
ref?.child("posts").child("somechild").observe(.value
```

Then have another function watching for changes:

```
ref?.child("posts").child("somechild").observe(.childChanged
```

But what is the difference between `.value` and `.childChanged` in `FIRDatabaseHandle` ?

Right now I am only using `.value` and I will both first fetch data then also watch for changes using it, so I dont need `.childChanged` and this makes me wonder what `.childChanged` is used for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Listen for value events**

To read data at a path and listen for changes, use the observeEventType:withBlock orobserveSingleEventOfType:withBlock methods of FIRDatabaseReference to observe FIRDataEventTypeValue events.

Event type  Typical usage
FIRDataEventTypeValue   Read and listen for changes to the entire contents of a path.
You can use the FIRDataEventTypeValue event to read the data at a given path, as it exists at the time of the event. This method is triggered once when the listener is attached and again every time the data, including any children, changes. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing all data at that location, including child data. If there is no data, the value of the snapshot returned is nil.

Comment: So then I should be able to just use ``ref?.child("posts").child("somechild").observe(.childChanged`` to read the data and check for changes? Also since I am targeting a specific child of a child I suppose I dont read the data for the entire node each time a change has been made?

Comment: Yea that's correct. Look in the console and make sure it doesn't suggest implementing and indexOf value for reading data as well. It would then speed up the read as your either not going to the root node, or you're explicitly defining your root.